# Does flatlist automatically support pagination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, react-native-flatlist

In my react native application I use a 'Flatlist' to render my products which are queried from backend as shown below. I want to know does this automatically has pagination or do I have to implement pagination manually, if so what is the best way to do it?

```
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import {Product} from "../src/models";

const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState <Product[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {

      const getallProducts = async () => {
  
        await DataStore.query(Product, a => a.Available("eq", true)).then(setAllProducts);
          
      };
      getallProducts();
      
  
    }, []);

<FlatList 
   data={allProducts}
   renderItem = {({item}) => <ProductComponent info={item}  />}
   numColumns={2}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea: Scroll to FlatList's bottom, call function get data and map response to current data.

You can do that with FlatList's props:

- [onEndReachedThreshold](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold): How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the bottom edge of the list.
- [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached): callback  when scroll position gets within onEndReachedThreshold.

AWS-amplify DataStore doc:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/#pagination

Example:

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState<number>(0)

const onLoadMore = async () => {
  await DataStore.query(Product, (a) => a.Available("eq", true)).then(
    () => setAllProducts([...allProducts, ...response.dataProducts]),
    { page: page, limit: 100 },
  )
  setPage(page + 1)
}

return (
  <FlatList
    data={allProducts}
    renderItem = {({item}) => <ProductComponent info={item} />}
    numColumns={2}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.2} // trigger onEndReached when the end of the content is within 20% the visible length of the list.
    onEndReached={onLoadMore}
  />
)
```

Comment: Thanks, But the whole point of pagination is to limit the number of queries, but this doesn't do it right? Because according to your code all the items are queried from the database each time

Comment: Sorry, i missing pagination params. you need pass page = number of items in 1 time get data.